# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000

Tags: aws-lambda, lite-server, aws-lambda-containers

We are using AWS Lambda runtime interface emulator to run our app locally inside Docker using lite-server

I start my docker container with:
docker run -p 9000:8080  image-name

The curl http://localhost:9000 command is returning
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000 after 0 ms: Connection refused

I am a newbie to Docker, can anyone please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure, the service in the container is listening on port 8080?

Comment: Not sure though, how can I check that?

Comment: In the configuration/documentation of the service you are running

Comment: I referred this to run the docker command - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator
where it is mentioned to run your container image locally using the docker run command.

docker run -p 9000:8080 myfunction:latest

Comment: when I try to do curl http://localhost:8080, I am getting
'404 page not found'